# Count total number of records in the view in yii

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

This is my view. I upload the records and if the record is not uploaded successfully it gives me an error. I am trying to get total number of records which work fine but when I try to get the "total number of record with error" , it gives me the "total number of error" itself. How can I only count the "records with error" and NOT the "number of error" itself?

```
$records = 0;
$errors = 0;
/* @var array $data */
foreach ($data as $result) {
    $records++;
    foreach ($result["model"]->getErrors() as $attribute => $errors) {
        $errors++;
    }
}
```

Comment: how is array `$data` created ? `findAll` ?

Comment: Did you mean "I UPDATE the records" instead? Check hasErrors() instead of getErrors(). It will just return true/false if there's at least 1 error with that model, following a validate() call

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a count everytime validation fails in your controller. Your question and code samples do not seem to be complete so I can only guess what you really want to do

```
$errorCount = 0;
if ($_POST['data']) {
    foreach ($_POST['data'] as $data) {
        // create a model (let's use $model for example) out of data received + other pre-validation work
        if ($model->validate) {
            // post validation work, then save
            $model->save(false);
        } else {
            $errorCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Issue has no words about `create` or `$_POST`...The problem was in the wrong counting. I think the issue has exhausted itself.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `validate()` method of model. Try this. Hope this help you.

```
/* @var array $data */
$allRecords = count($data);
$recordsWithErrors = 0;
foreach ($data as $result) {
    if (!$result['model']->validate()) {
        $recordsWithErrors++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use `validate()` into view.

Comment: @SiZE Can you explain why I should not use `validate` into views? It is just for fun ))))

Comment: Обиделся что ли? Просто отвечай по существу вопроса, будь внимательней.

Comment: @SiZE so... What about `validate` in view? )))

Comment: @SiZE I don't think that `$recordsWithErrors++;` is large business logic for view. It is just counter.

Comment: @SiZE dear developer, you think that my answer is useless. Furthermore you think that I never should use `validate()` in view. I don't think so. In some case we can use `validate()` in view.  I still waiting explanations.

Comment: "@Danila Ganchar" Create a new question for this, please.

Comment: @SiZE oooooh. I understood. You just click `votedown` and can't explain the reason. And of course you use something like `It's just an example, how make code nice, more readable ` and bla-bla-bla for justification. Сircus...

Answer (score -2):

First of all do it in you controller.

```
public function actionCreate(){
   // your code there
   $records_with_errors = 0;
   foreach ($data as $result) {
      // assumed that you validate models before count
      if ($result['model']->hasErrors()) {
          $records_with_errors++;
      }
   }

   $this->render('create', [
       'records_with_errors' => $records_with_errors
   ]);
}
```

Comment: Your solution does not works. Why? Because `hasErrors, getErrors` must calls after `validate`.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar You didn't noticed that TS asking about view, you didn't noticed my comments about validation in example. Be more attentive, please. It's just an example, how make code nice, more readable and solve authors problem `count the "records with error"`, not `validate and count`

Comment: You didn't noticed that the question is about wrong counting, but not about controllers, views, best practice etc.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar this is not best practice it's MVC. And my answer consider the part with question about counting. It seems you also didn't noticed that, too.

Comment: Well let's finish because it is ridiculous))). Good luck in development.